# get all the records count and first 100 records in hibernate and mysql

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, hibernate

I am using server side pagination.For that initially i need to show first 100 records first and the no of buttons on the top.For example total i have 550 records i need to show 6 buttons at the top.When user clicks on second button i need to retrieve 101 to 199 records.

To get the total records i am using one database call and to get the first 100 records i am using another database call.

I am using hibernate ,so the query is like this

```
 select model from TableName model where ................

   FirstResult = 0
   MaxResult = 100
```

And to get the total no of records i am using

```
   select count(*) from TableName model where ................
```

Here the problem is i am running the similar query for 2 times.
How i can combine these 2 queries into one?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: So what is the problem? Or you want to optimize it?

Comment: i need to combine into one query

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same query but conditions are very similar. There is nothing wrong to call 2 queries with common conditions.

Comment: Is there any possibility to combine.If the queries are getting small amount of data then ok.But they are getting huge amount of data.

Comment: select count(*) returns only 1 record. Where is huge amount of data coming from?

Comment: sorry.I mean it is going to process large amount of data.

Comment: One of solution is try to avoid counting at all in this case or get it approximately.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TableName`) FROM `TableName`
```

works but there's 2 queries

(Server version: 5.5.32-MariaDB-1~precise-log - mariadb.org binary distribution)

Answer (score 0):

you can use union in mysql 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

combine like this 
select model from TableName model where ................
UNION 
select count(*) from TableName model where ................

But you have to take care of separting the result of two queries